# PDO fetch returns only first row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the following code to make a connection to the database, fetch the `Data_length` index column, and calculate the database size based on the data.

For some reason PDO will always return "0", which is the value for the `Data_length` index in the first row. Whatever I do, I only get the first rows index.

The database is MySQL, the engine MyISAM.

PHP Version: 5.5.38
MySQL Version: 5.5.50

Here is the source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
try {
    error_reporting(-1);
    $host_name  = "my_host";
    $database   = "my_db";
    $user_name  = "my_user";
    $password   = "my_pwd";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name;dbname=$database", $user_name, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth = $conn->query('SHOW TABLE STATUS');
    $dbSize = 0;
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbSize = $row["Data_length"];
    $decimals = 2;  
    $mbytes = round($dbSize/(1024*1024),$decimals);
    echo $dbSize . "\n" . $row["Data_length"];
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `fetch` always return **one** row. Try to read manual from time to time....

Comment: You do need to read the manual ^^^^, but to get you started maybe [`->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) will help you with this specific issue

Comment: @Fred, this question is not exactly a duplicate of the other one. The other one is wrong, as it states that Data_length returns "0". This question is different. Please, reopen this one so I can delete the other one.

Comment: @nospor, actually I already did, also I already try fetchAll and etc. This is not the approach that I need. And also, I have read already a bunch of other questions about how to get database size and they all approach it more or less in this manner. Also this code is from another question checked as correct answer :/. I just added the error handling and my credentials.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any difference in code for both the questions.

Comment: @Fred, yes the code is the same, and it is the same as in the question from where I have copied it, but the question is not, and this one is correctly asked, the other is wrong as the problem is not the Data_length but instead the fact that there is only one row fetched. And it is misleading people, so please, let me delete it and keep this one.

Comment: @Fred, you can obviously see that the other question doesn't have any answers, either comments, and this one already has an answer and some comments. It is not the same.

Comment: what you should have done, was edit your other question, rather than reposting with the same code. Sorry, but I won't be reopening the question. I posted a few comments under your other question yesterday but didn't bother replying so I ended up deleting them. Stating that there was nothing wrong with your code since I tested it.

Comment: @Fred, Well this is a bit unfortunate don't you think? I copy this code from other questions, will you mark them as [Duplicate] also because they contain the same code?

Comment: @Fred, Please, consider reading my updates and also my other question so you can see that I provided an effective answer there, which on its turn is the question/problem in this topic.

Comment: i am lathe, but you are right fetch() return only one row, fetchall() return all row but with array index. The way is: fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOCH).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a while loop,

```
while($row= $sth->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
   echo $row['your_field_name'];
}
```

Or you can use `fetchAll`

```
$rows = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I already tried something similar. However, if you look at my source code you will see that I'm trying just to calculate the database size, and as I have done it before, the same way, it is very uncommon that now it's not working.

Comment: I select this as a correct answer because it fits in general with the question, even that it is not exactly what I needed. However, I found a workaround and now everything is working fine. Had to use a different SQL  query but finally achieved my goal

Comment: Why would `while()` return only one row? (I m converting mysqli prepared statements to PDO)

Comment: @Ignus ...well, I had the same problem, as you can see, in my previous comment I just solved this by the query, I don't remember how right now, it's like 6y l8tr xD Change your SQL query